# Python: RegisterUserView not saving to DB (or returning HttpResponse)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, view, modelform

**So I have a *simple* user registration form using: RegisterUserForm ModelForm and User Model**

Needs to:

- **it is suppose to create an instance of the modelform and validate the
  form and save the user data to db.**
- **- return HttpResponse('User Registered')**

**Issue**: *Register form displays, upon clicking submit button, doesn't do anything! Stays there (it should show a `HttpResponse('User Registered')`*

**View.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic import CreateView

from website.forms import RegisterUserForm
# Create your views here.
class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    template_name = "account/register.html"

    #  Overide dispatch func - check if the user is authenticated or return forbidden
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

        return super(RegisterUserView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # Overide form valid method behaviour
    def form_valid(self, form):
        #  False commit - don't save to db, locally cleaning users password first
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        user.save();
        # Change to redirect - later one! 
        return HttpResponse('User Registered')
```

**forms.py**

```
    from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        # Connect to the user model and select which fields we want input for user model
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


    # Validate password matched / and clean them
    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data

        if cd['password2'] != cd['password']:
            raise ValidationError("Password don't match")
        return cd['password2']
```

Register.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

{%  block title %}
Register
{% endblock %}

{% block heading %}
    <h1>Register</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post ">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Can you add `register.html` code also?

Comment: In your code, you have `retVurn HttpResponseForbidden()` maybe an error from there too ?

Comment: @deadpool sorry messed up the copy paste. fixed the question. Problem still there

Comment: @neverwalkaloner adding now

Comment: @Shaz try to remove action value. Try just this: `<form action="" method="post">`. Also remove space after `post` in form's method.

Comment: says not defined NameError at /account/register/
name 'HttpResponseForbidden' is not defined
Request Method: GET

Comment: @Shaz Did you add `from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden`to the file?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Yes, i have now, but the problem there: not returning  HttpResponse('User Registered')

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I've checked the database, its not adding the user in it!

Comment: Any more Ideas?